# Automatically maintain a total count of children in the parent table

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers, plpgsql

I have parent-child tables where I'd like to have an automatically stored count of the number of children in the parent record. Updates are not very frequent but reads are, so this is a number that seems sensible (to me) to cache. The tables may look something like this:

```
create table parent(
   id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
   numchildren integer not null default 0
);

create table child(
  id serial primary key
  parent_id integer NOT NULL REFERENCES parent(id)
);
```

I've added a trigger that would update `numchildren` but it always sets `numchildren` to the full total of records in the `child` table, not just of the count for the particular parent.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION run_after_change() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
  IF TG_OP = 'DELETE' THEN
    UPDATE parent 
       SET numchildren = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM child WHERE OLD.parent_id = parent.id) 
    WHERE OLD.parent_id = parent.id;
    RETURN OLD;
  ELSIF TG_OP = 'UPDATE' OR TG_OP = 'INSERT' THEN
    UPDATE parent 
      SET numchildren = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM child WHERE NEW.parent_id = parent.id) 
    WHERE NEW.parent_id = parent.id;
    RETURN NEW;
  END IF;
END; $$ language 'plpgsql';

CREATE TRIGGER after_change 
  AFTER DELETE OR INSERT OR UPDATE ON child 
  FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE run_after_change();
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Unrelated, but: the language name is an identifier. Don't put it in single quotes, use `language plpgsql` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your where clause for the `count(*)` query is wrong.

`parent.id` should be `parent_id` It should be:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM child WHERE parent_id = NEW.parent_id
```

(or `OLD.parent_id` for the `DELETE` part)